# How to include a jar in ADT Eclipse as normal?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am working on a android application i downloaded from GitHub

Its `Readme.md` file says 
"*copy the `dist/android-***-api-2.x.x.x.jar` file to your lib folder and link as normal.Supports Android Studio and Eclipse*"

What does it mean to link as normal?

I tried *Configure build path->Add jar* but that doesn't do anything?

I also tried copying the jar to lib folder. how do i link it now?

Comment: Could you post the link of the project in github?

Comment: sorry, its a private repository. I don't have the permission to do so.